# What is the name of the algorithm for multiplying two digit numbers by 11 in you head by adding the two digits to make the middle result digit?

Tags: algorithms

My father(70, I’m 40) said:

> You can multiply two digit numbers by 11 in your head by adding your two digits and inserting it in the middle of your original two digits. So 13 x 11 => 1 + 3 = 4 => 143

This process must have a name in the mathematical world.

My question is: **What is the name of the algorithm for multiplying two digit numbers by 11 in you head by adding the two digits to make the middle result digit?**

Comment: "This process must have a name in the mathematical world."  Why do you think that?  These are precisely the type of things that tend *not* to have names.

Comment: Multiplication is a convolution.

Answer (score 1):

The multiplication algorithm is a [*convolution*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) of the digits - at least as long as no overflow (carry) occurs.